# ASP.NET MVC enum argument in controller mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routeconfig

ASP.NET MVC provides simple templates for controller methods such as `Details`, and can have something like:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    // do something
}
```

This can be accessed by: `http://localhost:port/Controller/Details/id`

What I'm trying to do is instead provide a different type like:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    All,
    Pending,
    Complete
}
```

And then I setup my controller method like:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.Pending)
{
    // do something
}
```

This works fine for: `http://localhost:port/Controller/MyMethod/` because it uses the default argument.

To specify a different argument I have to do `http://localhost:port/Controller/MyMethod?myEnum=All` and that works.

I'm wondering, is it possible for me to be able to do `http://localhost:port/Controller/MyMethod/All` instead of using `?myEnum=All`?

Upon trying to do it that way I get a `404` exception which is understandable, but why doesn't this happen for `id` in `Details`?

Can I change the `MapRoute` which is currently: `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"` to allow me to achieve it with my own type?

#### What I've tried so far:

I only want this route enforcement for one of my schemes such as `http://localhost:port/Controller/MyMethod/{ViewType}`, I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs) but it doesn't seem to do anything:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyRoute",
    "MyController/Index/{MyEnum}",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Pending" }
);
```

Comment: Yes. You should however add a new route to handle that scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/Controller/MyMethod/All` will actually work. The problem is with the default route, which will consider `All` to be the `id` route parameter, which doesn't line up with what your action is using as a parameter. It would actually work fine if your action signature was:

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyEnum id = MyEnum.Pending)
```

Since it will then bind `All` to the right thing.

You *could* add another route for this use-case, but you'll need to be careful that you don't just create another "default" route, which will take over. In other words, you'll have to fix part of the URL:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyCustomRoute",
    "Controller/{action}/{myEnum}",
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "MyMethod", myEnum = MyEnum.Pending }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```

Then, by the mere presence of the `/Controller/` prefix to the route, it will use your custom route instead, and fill in `All` for the `myEnum` param, rather than hitting the default route and try to fill in `id`.

However, be advised that when using enums as route params, they must be *exact matches*. So, while `/Controller/MyMethod/All` will work, `/Controller/MyMethod/all` will not. To get around this, you'll have to create a custom model binder. I did a quick search and found the following [article](http://www.patridgedev.com/2011/08/18/handling-case-insensitive-enum-action-method-parameters/) which may help you in that regard.

Comment: This works, my follow up question is: if I was to set `MyMethod` to be: `public ActionResult MyMethod(MyEnum id= MyEnum.Pending)` will that be equivalent to not enforcing a custom `MapRoute`? Furthermore, where you have `myEnum = MyEnum.Pending` is that the default value if `myEnum` is null? So I can possibly remove the default argument from my controller?

Comment: In regards to case-sensitivity, my controller seems to pick it up fine. Even so far as going `/Controller/MyMethod/cOmPLeTe`, not sure what's happening there.

Comment: They two defaults are for different things. The route default is for if the param is not provided in the URL at all. The default on the action signature is for if the provided value cannot be bound for whatever reason.

Comment: The case sensitivity issue may have been solved in an update to MVC. If it works fine for you, then great.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed. Do not change the default route `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"`, but rather add one before the default. This new one needs to be fairly specific:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "EnumRoute",
    "Controller/MyMethod/{myEnum}",
    new { controller = "Controller", action = "MyMethod", myEnum = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

What that basically says is "when you see request to literally Controller/MyMethod/whatever, use this controller and that method and pass whatever as parameter of the request". Note that actual controller does not necessary have to be what route says in the url, although it is a good idea to stick to that.

Comment: Do I still need to have the default `MyEnum` argument set in `MyMethod`? Also, I tried this but it doesn't seem to do anything, it enforces the default parameter only.