# Own Enum in route param, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, enums

I have a simple Api function:

```
// POST: api/Cultivation/Sow/1/5
[HttpGet("Sow/{grain}/{id}")]
public IActionResult Sow(Grain grain, int id) { }
```

My enum looks like this:

```
public enum Grain
{
    None,
    Rice,
    Corn,
    Oats
}
```

My question is, is it possible to get `Grain` or any enum from Route? When Yes, how to do it?

If No, how to "find" enum by int in elegant way, without if statements etc? Because if myWebapi cant take `enums`, it is easy to do by simple `int`

Comment: Check this out :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254852/asp-net-mvc-enum-argument-in-controller-mapping

Comment: Thanks, it is really helpful, but im looking easy way to do it by attributes because i looking for easy setup way for it. If it is impossible to get enum by simple `Route` attribute, i will go for `int` ;)

Comment: Simple cast like `(Grain)grain` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-routing-middleware

Hope this helps.

You can add url as you shown

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{grain=somedefault}/{id?}");
});
```

> Tokens within curly braces ({ ... }) define route parameters that are
>   bound if the route is matched. You can define more than one route
>   parameter in a route segment, but they must be separated by a literal
>   value. For example, {controller=Home}{action=Index} isn't a valid
>   route, since there's no literal value between {controller} and
>   {action}. These route parameters must have a name and may have
>   additional attributes specified.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public enum EnumReviewStatus
{
    Overdue = 4,
}

public IActionResult Index(EnumReviewStatus? statusFilter = null)
```

url **Index?statusFilter=Overdue** is work

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
[HttpGet("Sow/{id}/{grain}")]
public IActionResult Sow( int id , Grain grain = Grain.none) { }
```

Comment: Be careful about this - Only one action using an enum can exist.  If you try 2 or more actions with different enums it will not work and result in a 500 error.